# Check if a file contains multiple patterns

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

I want to know how to `grep` multiple suggestions from a file only if the condition is true.

Example.

file.txt contains

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
```

If I do a grep AA & ZZ from file.txt. it should not give any output since it has no ZZ pattern in it. It should satisfy both the condition. Awk or sed anything is fine

Comment: Please specify your shell. Also do you mean that AA BB CC DD must be on the same line or only in the same file?

Comment: @Harish Selvam : Can you elaborate your requirement with more content ?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
grep -vf <(grep -f patterns_file file) patterns_file
```

If you want to cross check if a file contains all the given patterns, you can use the following approach:

- Store the patterns in a different file, one in a different line.
- `grep` the original file against this patterns file.
- Finally, `grep` this result against the patterns file, with the inverted flag. This way, all the remaining patterns will show. If the result is empty, it means that everything was found.

File with the data:

```
$ cat data
AA
BB
CC
DD
```

File with the patterns:

```
$ cat pat 
AA
CC
TT
```

Check for matches in `data`

```
$ grep -f pat data
AA
CC
```

Check if any of the patterns remain unfound:

```
$ grep -vf <(grep -f pat data) pat
TT
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like this:

```
awk '/AA/{f=a=1} /ZZ/{f=z=1} f{hits=hits $0 ORS; f=0} END{if (a && z) printf "%s", hits}'
```

to handle the cases where AA and/or ZZ appear multiple times, possible interleaved with each other, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
a
AA
b
AA
c
ZZ
d
AA
e
ZZ
f

$ awk '/AA/{f=a=1} /ZZ/{f=z=1} f{hits=hits $0 ORS; f=0} END{if (a && z) printf "%s", hits}' file
AA
AA
ZZ
AA
ZZ
```

The general solution to find any number of regexps in the file, btw, would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(tgts,tmp)
    for (idx in tmp) {
        wanted[tmp[idx]]
    }
}
{
    found = 0
    for (regexp in wanted) {
        if ($0 ~ regexp) {
            found = 1
            seen[regexp]
        }
    }
}
found {
    hits = hits $0 ORS
}
END {
    if ( length(wanted) == length(seen) ) {
        printf "%s", hits
    }
}

$ awk -v tgts="AA ZZ" -f tst.awk file
AA
AA
ZZ
AA
ZZ
```

String instead of regexp matching would be:

```
    for (string in wanted) {
        if (index($0,string) {
            found = 1
            seen[string]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you search with

```
grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 ... file
```

Comment: because patterns are in different lines